# PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $user = $_SESSION['login'];
    $mysql_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $mysql_select_db = mysql_select_db("site");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `msg_inbox` WHERE `to` = '$user'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
            $mysql_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            $mysql_select_db = mysql_select_db("site");
            $query = ("UPDATE msg_inbox  SET unread = 0 WHERE id= ".$row['id']);
            $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
```

And I receive error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in  on line 8
Can you help me?

Comment: [Exploits of a mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Are you sure that your `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` worked? Try adding an `or die` statement for those.

Comment: Looking at the "Related" section here, I think there might be some duplicates to this question..

Comment: Does `var_dump($mysql_connect);` output "Ressource xy"?

Comment: Answer of DaveRandom tells everything. Another problem is sometimes, using a bit more complex querys, that the query is not valid. In these cases, just output the query, copy and paste it and execute it manually in your database (preferred PhpMyAdmin), this will show you the errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have reassigned `$result` in your loop. After the first iteration, the variable `$result` will hold a boolean indicating the success or failure of your `UPDATE` statement.

Change:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

To:

```
$result2 = mysql_query($query);
```

Or just:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

And be careful of SQL injection holes.

**EDIT** actually, your whole code could and should be shortened to:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $user = $_SESSION['login'];
  // A blank password for root? Really?
  $mysql_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  $mysql_select_db = mysql_select_db("site");
  $sql = "
    UPDATE `msg_inbox`
    SET `unread` = 0
    WHERE `to` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'
  ";
  // Don't show the result of mysql_error() in a production environment!
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You inner query is overwriting `$result`, causing the outer loop to fail.

As well, you're opening a new connection inside the loop. This is highly inefficient and wasteful. Let's say your main query finds 500 rows. That means you're opening 500 connectsion to mysql. This is utterly pointless.

Comment: Not only that, he is looping a result set and updating the table the results came from based solely on the IDs of the returned rows - the whole thing can be summed up in a single `UPDATE`.

Comment: @dave: not really. the update would be writing to the same table which the select is coming from. Can't be done in mysql as a `update ... where in (select from...)` type query. There are workarounds, of course.

Comment: Why can't he just do `UPDATE msg_inbox SET unread = 0 WHERE to = '$user'`?

Comment: Ah yeah... good point. I think I'll just slink off to get a coffee and finish waking up.

Comment: See I am cheating by living in a timezone where it's nearly 3pm. Doesn't mean I'm awake, of course...

Comment: @DaveRandom: Well, to get incredibly nitpicky, if the database had such a terrible design as there may be duplicate IDs, then you might need a `where in` clause in order to update all records that have the same ID as `$user`, so if the database design was terrible and they were trying to do something dumb...technically he's right :-)